# Convert Delphi to Java (my code is correct?)

Tags: java, delphi

I have this Delphi code

```
const
  C1 = 52845;
  C2 = 22719;

Function Encrypt(const S: String; Key: Word): String; cdecl ;
var
  I: byte;
  J : Integer;
  Str : String ;
begin
      Str := S ;
      for I := 1 to Length(S) do begin
        J:=byte(S[I]) xor (Key shr 8);
        Str[I] := Char(J);
        Key := (byte(Str[I]) + Key) * C1 + C2;
      end;
      Result:= '';
      for I := 1 to Length(S) do begin
        Result:= Result + StringOfChar('0' , 3 - Length(IntToStr(byte(Str[I]))) ) + IntToStr(byte(Str[I]));
      end;
end;
```

I want convert this code to java

I write this

```
 public static String EncryptePassword(String S,int Key){
        int C1 = 52845;
        int C2 = 22719;

        String Str=S;
        String Result="";
        int J;
        for(int i=0;i<S.length();i++){

            J = (byte) S.charAt(i) ^ (byte) (Key>> 8);
            Str+= (char) J;
            Key=((byte) Str.charAt(i)+Key)*C1+C2;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<S.length();i++){
            Result+=repeat("0",3-String.valueOf( Integer.valueOf((byte) Str.charAt(i))).length())+ (byte) Str.charAt(i);

        }
        return Result;
    }
```

This java code is equal to Delphi code?

Comment: Does it produce the desired results in your own tests?

Comment: Don't roll your own encryption, you WILL get it wrong and cause a security hole. Use one of the many libraries available in java.

Comment: Please learn to do this yourself. Try running your programs and feeding them the same input. Please don't ask questions like this here.

Comment: Also, where did you get the Delphi code? Because I see `cdecl` indicating this function was written for a DLL, but at the same time, `String` is used, which should never be used through DLL boundaries.

Comment: Also, when dealing with bit shifting, it is important to understand the differences between data types.  `Word` and `int`, for example, are not the same.  `Word` is 16-bit unsigned, `int` is 32-bit signed...

Comment: @JerryDodge please help me i does not know Delphi,and i must convert it to java

Comment: Why not hire a programmer that does know it. Any good programmer would knock this off in 15 minutes.

Comment: While I agree this may be a poorly asked question, I highly disagree with the votes to close as "Unclear what you're asking". It's extremely clear. OP is asking if the Delphi code was successfully converted to the Java code.

Comment: @ashkufaraz If I knew Java, I would be able to give you a definite answer. But what I can advise, as mentioned already, is to use an existing encryption library, because this version will most definitely be vulnerable to hacking. Any hacker could crack this in a matter of 20 minutes, if they really wanted to.

Comment: @JerryDodge: *Unclear* is the catch-all reason for *your question makes no sense*. The first comment to this post (made by you, BTW) is the reason it's unclear. The poster should be able to tell if the two code versions produce the same result, even if they don't know one of the languages used.

Comment: The question is patently not 'unclear' because it has received a detailed answer from a person with a long track record of knowing what they are talking about, and the answer has been accepted.

Comment: @Chris Of course it is possible to translate code from Delphi to Java. But such a question is not a good fit here. You can argue about the close reason if you wish. But it should be closed. If you disagree take it to meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is not equivalent.  In particular, this line in Delphi:

```pascal
Str[I] := Char(J);
```

is replacing a character inside the string, whereas this line in Java:

```java
Str += (char) J;
```

is appending a character to the end of the string instead.

So `Str` will have two different results.

In Java, strings are immutable, you cannot modify characters.  But you can construct a new string with pieces from an old string and then replace the old string with the new string.  Or better, you can use a StringBuilder instead.

The translation to Java might look something more like this:

```java
private static int C1 = 52845;
private static int C2 = 22719;

private static int toUnsignedByte(char c)
{
    // in Delphi, Byte is an 8-bit unsigned type, but Java does not have
    // an equivalent type. Casting a Char to a Byte truncates the value
    // to 8 bits. Use a signed integer and limit its value to the
    // same range as a Byte...
    //
    return ((int) c) & 0xFF;
}

public static String EncryptePassword(String S, int Key)
{
    // in Delphi, Word is a 16-bit unsigned type, but Java does not have
    // an equivalent type. Use a signed integer and limit its value
    // to the same range as a Word...
    //
    if ((Key < 0) or (Key > 0xFFFF))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key is outside the valid range of values");

    int J;
    StringBuilder Str = new StringBuilder(S);

    for(int I = 0; I < S.length(); ++I)
    {
        J = toUnsignedByte(S.charAt(I)) ^ (Key >> 8);
        Str.setCharAt(I, (char) J);
        Key = ((toUnsignedByte(Str.charAt(I)) + Key) * C1 + C2) & 0xFFFF;
    }

    StringBuilder Result = new StringBuilder(S.length() * 3);

    for(int I = 0; I < S.length(); ++I)
    {
        Result.append(String.format(Locale.US, "%03d", toUnsignedByte(Str.charAt(I))));
    }

    return Result.toString();
}
```

However, something else to keep in mind is that in Delphi 2007 and earlier, `String` is an 8-bit Ansi string, but in Delphi 2009 and later it is a 16-bit Unicode string instead.  Java strings are 16-bit Unicode.  You did not say which version of Delphi you are trying to port the code from, but if it is an Ansi version then the translation might look more like this instead:

```java
private static int C1 = 52845;
private static int C2 = 22719;

private static int toUnsignedByte(byte b)
{
    // in Delphi, Byte is an 8-bit unsigned type, but Java does not have
    // an equivalent type. Casting an AnsiChar to a Byte leaves the value
    // as-is as 8 bits. Use a signed integer and limit its value to the
    // same range as a Byte...
    //
    return ((int)b) & 0xFF;
}

public static String EncryptePassword(String S, int Key)
{
    // in Delphi, Word is a 16-bit unsigned type, but Java does not have
    // an equivalent type. Use a signed integer and limit its value
    // to the same range as a Word...
    //
    if ((Key < 0) or (Key > 0xFFFF))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key is outside the valid range of values");

    byte[] Str = S.getBytes(); // <-- you might need to specify a charset to get the correct bytes!
    int J;

    for(int I = 0; I < Str.length; ++I)
    {
        J = toUnsignedByte(Str[I]) ^ (Key >> 8);
        Str[I] := (byte) J;
        Key = ((toUnsignedByte(Str[I]) + Key) * C1 + C2) & 0xFFFF;
    }

    StringBuilder Result = new StringBuilder(Str.length * 3);

    for(int I = 0; I < Str.length; ++I)
    {
        Result.append(String.format(Locale.US, "%03d", toUnsignedByte(Str[I])));
    }

    return Result.toString();
}
```